# Geopandas contains working for one point but not many

Tags: python, geopandas

I need filter rows of a dataframe within a multipolygon. My multypolygon is stored in gdf_polygon and my points are stored in gdf. Here is a bit resume of how they look.

```
gdf_polygon
id          geometry
0           MULTIPOLYGON (((39.81239 21.43429, 39.81445 21...

gdf
id      geometry
0       POINT (50.05832 26.43992)
...     ...
```

The problem is that when I tried to check if there are any points inside it return `False`, but I know there are some points inside the polygon.

Basically, if I run this I have `False` as output.

```
gdf_polygon.geometry.contains(gdf.geometry).any()
```

Otherwise, if I run this I have `True` as output, because that point is inside the polygon.

```
gdf_polygon.geometry.contains(gdf.geometry[141828])
```

I know I could iterate through all the rows of `gdf` and run the contains for each one, but since my dataset is quite big (around 30.000.000 rows) that would be very inefficient. So I was looking for an explanation or possible fixes.

My dataframes creations is:

```
 crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

 df = pd.read_csv(FOLDER+file, compression='gzip', escapechar='\\')

 geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

 inside = gdf.geometry.within(gdf_polygon.geometry)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing two GeoSeries in `contains` geopandas aligns them, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345785/geopandas-intersect-function-gives-different-result-to-shapely/345822#345822 for explanation.

To make your code work as intended, you need to compare your GeoSeries of points with the multi polygon geometry itself. And do it vice versa, using `within`.

```
polygon = gdf_polygon.geometry.iloc[0]
gdf.geometry.within(polygon)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so troubled since this information doesn't appear in the geopandas documentation.